# jQuery hover parent affect child

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am curious to know, how you target a child, when hover on a parent?

How I would do in CSS:

```
parent:hover child {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

How do you do this in jQuery? ***".medarbejdere .info span.kontaktinfo"*** is my Parent. I would like ***$(this)*** to be my child.

```
var navDuration = 150; //time in miliseconds
  var forstoer = "150px";

  $('.medarbejdere .info span.kontaktinfo').hover(function() {
      $(this).animate({ 'right' : "+="+forstoer }, navDuration);            
  }, function() {
      $(this).animate({ 'right' : "-150px" }, navDuration);
    });
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this).children()`.

Ex:

```
var navDuration = 150; //time in miliseconds 
var forstoer = "150px"; 

$('.medarbejdere .info span.kontaktinfo').hover(function() { 
    $(this).children().animate({ 'right' : "+="+forstoer }, navDuration);             
}, function() { 
    $(this).children().animate({ 'right' : "-150px" }, navDuration); 
});
```

Comment: What if you want to target a child 3 (child of a child of a child)??

In CSS it would be:
parent:hover child1 child2 child3 {
//magic
}

Comment: @Kenneth B -- use classes and class selectors?  Seriously, I would expect these to be related somehow and assigning them a class that you can then use to apply behavior (or styling) to them would be much easier than complicated traversal rules.

Comment: I'm making a website for a client, which is very dynamic because of jQuery. It can't be done with pure CSS.

Comment: @Kenneth B -- I never said that you should only use CSS, but you can still apply classes either server-side or using jQuery, then take advantage of those classes in your javascript code.  For example, use a class to mark a menu item, like `<a href="/controller/action" class="menu-item">Menu Item</a>`, then use a class selector to add the hover animations, `$('.menu-item').hover( in, out )` or a click handler `$('.menu-item').click( function() { ... } )`.